# Java excplicit cast of nested maps

Tags: java, collections, casting

Why does this cast work?

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class TestMap {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Map<String,Integer>>>> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, Object> aMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        Map<String, Integer> hiddenMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        hiddenMap.put("fortytwo", 42);
        aMap.put("key", hiddenMap);
        resultMap =  (Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>>>) aMap.get("key");
        System.out.println(resultMap);
    }
}
```

also this:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Map<String,Map<String,Integer>>>>> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
...
resultMap =  (Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Map<String,Map<String,Integer>>>>>) aMap.get("key");
```

and so on...

How does this happen that the hidden map which is `Map<String, Integer>` gets successfully cast to `Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Map<String,Integer>>>> resultMap`?

Always prints:

`{fortytwo=42}`

Also this works (Map instead of Map):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Map<String,Map<String,Integer>>>>> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, Map> aMap = new HashMap<String, Map>();
        Map<String, Integer> hiddenMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        hiddenMap.put("fortytwo", 42);
        aMap.put("key", hiddenMap);
        resultMap =  (Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Map<String,Map<String,Integer>>>>>) aMap.get("key");
        System.out.println(resultMap);

    }
```

EDIT: So as @shizhz says, it is because of Type Erasure of course! So the code above is equivalent to:

```
Map resultMap = new HashMap();
Map aMap = new HashMap();
Map hiddenMap = new HashMap();
hiddenMap.put("fortytwo", 42);
aMap.put("key", hiddenMap);
resultMap = (Map) aMap.get("key");
```

Which also works

Comment: At runtime, a `Map` is a `Map` and does not know what base type it has. You probably got a warning in your compiler, didn't you?

Comment: @RealSkeptic, yes the warning is there. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because java generics is used at compile time to provide tighter type checks, the type parameter is erased by compiler according [Type Erasure rules](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html):

- Replace all type parameters in generic types with their bounds or Object if the type parameters are unbounded. The produced bytecode, therefore, contains only ordinary classes, interfaces, and methods.
- Insert type casts if necessary to preserve type safety.
- Generate bridge methods to preserve polymorphism in extended generic types.

In code `Map<String, Map> aMap = new HashMap<String, Map>();`, the value in `aMap` is a raw type `Map`, which means the compiler has no idea what's the type it contains, when you try to cast a raw type of `Map` to any generics type of `Map` like `Map<String, Integer>`, the best compiler can do is giving you a warning. The generic type is erased at compile time and type cast will be generated when you get value from a generic map, so you can only get a **runtime** `ClassCastException` exception if the type mismatchs.

Let's have a look at the following example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map map = new HashMap();

    map.put("hello", "world");
    map.put(new Integer(1), 1);
    map.put(new Object(), Lists.newArrayList("hello"));

    Map<String, Integer> m =  (Map<String, Integer>) map;
    System.out.println(m);

    Integer i = m.get("hello");// ClassCastException happens at here at runtime
}
```

I'm trying to convert a `Map` containing all kinds of keys and values to `Map<String, Integer>` but there's no compile error, after type erasure, the above code is actually equivalent to:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map map = new HashMap();

    map.put("hello", "world");
    map.put(new Integer(1), 1);
    map.put(new Object(), Lists.newArrayList("hello"));

    Map m = (Map) map;
    System.out.println(m);

    Integer i = (Integer)m.get("hello");
}
```

Now you can easily tell why the last line caused `ClassCastException`.

Comment: Very glad to help:-)

Answer (score 3):

Since you've declared `aMap` as `Map<String, Object>`, the compiler cannot tell if the values won't indeed be of type `Map<String, Map<String, Map<String,Integer>>>`. It will just give you an "Unchecked cast" warning to let you think about the consequences.

The cast works unless you're actually trying to do something with the values:

```
resultMap.get("fortytwo").isEmpty();
```

will result in

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
  java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.util.Map
```

If you had declared `aMap` as `Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>>>>` you wouldn't be able to put `hiddenMap` in it in the first place.

Comment: Yes, but `toString()` works on the `resultMap` ... I understand that the compiler doesn't know, but the map get populated during runtime and it somehow maps the hidden map correctly.

Comment: why are you trying to `resultMap.get("fortytwo").isEmpty();`? `resultMap.get("fortytwo")` returns an `Integer`

Comment: Yes, that's because the `ClassCastException` is thrown. But the compiler _allows_ the call to `isEmpty` because with your explicit cast you made it treat it as `Map<String, Map>`. I was trying to demonstrate type erasure, but shizhz did a better job ;)